# How do I add a folder/group to SCM (CVS) in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, cvs

I have an iPhone project in Xcode which is checked into CVS via XCode's SCM support.

I have created a new folder in this project, and created a group for it's files. However, the files in this group/folder are not in CVS, and I cannot figure out how to get them in there. The usual "Add to repository" under the "SCM" menu is always grayed-out when I try to select one of the files - I would assume this is because the folder is not in CVS.

How do I add the folder/files to CVS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use several IDEs.  I usually only use the built-in source control tie-in for diffs.

```
$ xxx add dir-name
```

from the bash prompt should work, whether *xxx* is cvs, svn or git.

Probably not the answer you want, but it always works.

Comment: Worked like a charm (the XCode env was updated once reopened). If you're wondering (like I was) this command is recursive.